# Why do I have to specify the -i switch with a backup extension when using ActivePerl?

Tags: perl, activeperl

I cannot get in-place editing Perl one-liners running under ActivePerl to work unless I specify them with a backup extension:

```
C:\> perl -i -ape "splice (@F, 2, 0, q(inserted text)); $_ = qq(@F\n);" file1.txt
Can't do inplace edit without backup.
```

The same command with `-i.bak` or `-i.orig` works a treat but creates an unwanted backup file in the process.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is a Windows/MS-DOS limitation. According to [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html):

> You're on a system such as MS-DOS that gets confused if you try reading from a deleted (but still opened) file. You have to say -i.bak, or some such.

Perl's `-i` implementation causes it to delete `file1.txt` while keeping an open handle to it, then re-create the file with the same name. This allows you to 'read' file1.txt even though it has been deleted and is being re-created. Unfortunately, Windows/MS-DOS does not allow you to delete a file that has an open handle attached to it, so this mechanism does not work.

Your best shot is to use `-i.bak` and then delete the backup file. This at least gives you some protection - for example, you could opt not to delete the backup if `perl` exits with a non-zero exit code. Something like:

```
perl -i.bak -ape "splice...." file1.txt && del file1.bak
```

Comment: So it is a Windows limitation. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to `unlink` the backup with a separate command... looks like I'll have to. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not entirely related, but in-place editing on sed in windows seems to work for me.  I can see that your example wouldn't work in sed, but it might be helpful to know.

Comment: @Mike: On my end, `sed` in-place editing leaves temporary files like e.g. `sedGihEwg` in the file system - yours doesn't? Which version have you got? I'm using `GNU sed version 4.2.1`.

Comment: @Zaid IMO it's a poo Perl implementation rather than a Windows limitation. If you port a program to another OS, your port has to account for the quirks of that OS, and Perl doesn't seem to bother in this case.

Comment: And by poo I mean poor. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Sample with recursive modify and delete both done by find. Works on e.g. mingw git bash on windows.

```
$ find . -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 perl -p -i.bak -e 's#\s*<property name="blah" value="false" />\s*##g'
$ find . -name "*.bak" -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Binary terminated values passed between find/xargs to handle spaces. Unusual s/ prefix to avoid mangling xml in search term. This assumes you didn't have any `.bak` files hanging around to begin.