# Finding and deleting lines less than X chars long

Tags: perl

I have a list of items in a file,

```
foobar
barfoo
bar
faaboo
foo
boofar
fo
b
```

Using perl, I'm just after script that will go through the filename and delete all items 3 characters or less. Overwrite the existing filename (without creating a new, or temp filename), Thus the list will be become.

```
foobar
barfoo
faaboo
boofar
```

Comment: What have you tried? Is there a specific point that is creating a problem or do you just want someone to give you a ready-made script?

Comment: I suppose using perl to call out to the system `ed` program oughtn’t count. ☺

Comment: @tchrist - `ed` is for wusses. You call out to emacs and tell emacs to do this (i am kind of hoping emacs has such non-interactive capabilities)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One-liner:

```
perl -ine '{print if /.{4}/}' filename
```

You can use `length` (add 1 for newline character) instead of regex if that's your fancy, as Jonathan Leffler noted in comments - it's probably faster on very large files. Here's a Windows version (note the use of double quotes required by `cmd` instead of single quotes):

```
perl.exe -i.bak -n -e "{print if length > 4}" filename
```

Also, to answer your comment, unfortunately **you can not execute in-place `-i` edits on Windows without a backup file**. Please refer [to this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616865/why-do-i-have-to-specify-the-i-switch-with-a-backup-extension-when-using-activep/2616900#2616900) for detailed explanation (again, Windows limitation, not Perl's) as well as a workaround.

Comment: C:\Users\user>perl -ine '{/.{4}/}' list.txt
Can't open perl script "'{/.{4}/}'": No such file or directory

Comment: If it's Windows, you MUST use double quotes instead of single (`cmd` shell issue, nothing to do with Perl): `perl  -i.bak -n -e "{print if /.{4}/}" x.txt` - please note that this version actually just ran on my ActiveState Perl successfully :)

Comment: @user You should be familiar enough with your operating system to realize that whereas standard Unix shells are perfectly happy with single quotation marks in this context, with `cmd.exe`, you must use double quotation marks as in: `perl -i.bak -ne "{print if /.{4}/}" filename`

Comment: Anything wrong with `length` instead of a regex?   One possible objection - length would include the newline.  But `perl -ine 'print if length > 4'` does the required job, as does `perl -ine "print if length > 3 + 1"` (avoiding the problems on DOS, and leaving the 3 visible).

Comment: is it possible to avoid the -i.bak backup file?

Comment: @user349418 It is indeed, just leave out the -i.bak bit. That way your original file will be overwritten (which seems to be what you want). Btw, that's something you could have easily tried out yourself!

Comment: @user349418 - it's needed. I updated the answer with the link to complete explanation as well as actual Windows command

Comment: @canavanin - removing `-i.bak` will NOT do in-place edit like the OP wanted, and instead print the resulting text to standard out.

Comment: The `length` version will be faster, though not noticeably so unless your file is gigantic.

Comment: @DVK Oh, yes, you are right! Still you can stop backup file generation if you just put -i instead of -i.bak. (ok, just read your edit... If you say it cannot be done in Windows then I'll just have to believe you, as I can't try that out :) )

Comment: @canavanin I did remove it, but it just printed the file to the screen without making any changes to the file

Answer (score 4):

[Tie::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Tie::File;

my $file = shift;
tie my @array, 'Tie::File', $file or die;
@array = grep { length > 3 } @array;
untie @array;
```

Comment: Its worth noting that `tie` is generally expensive.

Comment: I tried the script, seems to work well, just took a lot longer (the txt file is around 230k in size)

Comment: +1 for actual in-place editing, but as user said, please be aware that Tie is SLOOOOW.