# using variable in search n replaces in perl

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I'm facing issues while trying to use the search n replace option in perl.

This is not an issue in the unix but appears only in windows. I'm using variable to search a file and replace it with desired string.
Also I'm using it in a one liner in a perl script, so it just adds to the problem!

```
$oldstring = 1234;
$newstring = 6789;

system("perl -pi.back e s/$oldstring/$newstring/g $filename");
```

I'm retrieving the file names in a directory from an array and passing them as input to the one-liner. There seems to be no change in the output files, but it does not report any warnings or failures either.

I tried the following too,

```
system("perl -pi.back e 's/$oldstring/$newstring/g' $filename");
```

Why is the search n replace not working as expected?

Comment: This is not valid perl `$oldstring = 1234 $newstring = 6789`. Missing a `;` at the end of each line. Please post the actual code you are running.

Comment: @ztirom - thanks for the formatting edit

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche - sorry this is my first post here. It is a big script, I was just trying to post only the relevant part here. still it was mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need appropriate quoting for `system()` and for command line,

```
system(qq(perl -pi.back -e "s/$oldstring/$newstring/g" $filename));
```

or use simpler and more efficient system without calling shell,

```
system("perl", "-pi.back", "-e", "s/$oldstring/$newstring/g", $filename);
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. Does this one liner not work in windows without creating a back file? There seems to be no issues in unix though.

Comment: @joe check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616865/why-do-i-have-to-specify-the-i-switch-with-a-backup-extension-when-using-active