# search string and replace corresponding number in windows env

Tags: windows, perl, shell, powershell, cygwin

I have one file and replace string :

sample file is:

`DP_SESSION_ID is a sting for values
DP_SESSION_ID is aplicat
"DP_S42SETTACC_TYPE"\1\"02"
"DP_SAP_CLIENT"\1\"460"
"DP_SAP_COMM_CONNECTION"\1\"JAVA_COMM_TOOL_ANALYZER"
"DP_SAP_CONNECTION"\1\"JAVA_TOOL_ANALYZER"
"DP_SAP_TOOLBI_CONNECTION"\1\"JAVA_TOOLBI_ANALYZER"
"DP_SESSION_ID"\1\"808"`

I want search this  "DP_SESSION_ID"\1\" sting and replace corresponding number like 808 in file prenatally(windows env), and i wand sing line command in windows bat command or perl command i don't want scrip or program

even i have installed  cygwin tool in my server so unix also ok but single line command

server: windows 2008,cygwin x

using tool : datastage server jobs

`perl -pi -e 's{" "DP_SESSION_ID"\1\"808 '"}{' "DP_SESSION_ID"\1\"900 '"'"}g' " file name`

this code is not working

Please give good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't use single-quotes in DOS the way you can in UNIX.  Second, you need to specify a backup file/extension when you use "-i" in DOS.  Third, I think you skip trying to match all those complicated quotes and go with a simpler approach.  It may not be the most efficient (using 2 regex) but it's very readable (to me).

This works for me:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e "m/\"DP_SESSION_ID\"/ && s/808/900/g" "filename"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: in file same line have double-quotes and same lines don't have double-quotes like "DP_SESSION_ID"\1\" ,/DP_SESSION_ID/ but i want quotes string only

Comment: Updated the one-liner to handle quotes around DP_SESSION_ID.

Comment: Thank u it's working but a small question i don't need bak file i want change directly file.if there is any option

Comment: According to this other item on this website, it can't be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616865/why-do-i-have-to-specify-the-i-switch-with-a-backup-extension-when-using-active

Comment: thank you for ur quick responds

Comment: Sure, don't forget to "accept" one of the answers!  That's an important part of how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

in powershell, you can try the command as below:

```
get-content input.txt |foreach-object {$_ -replace '"DP_SESSION_ID"\\1\\"808"', '"DP_SESSION_ID"\1\"900"'} | set-content output.txt
```

Comment: In this command is not working in cmd any option execute cmd power shell commands